# iPhone - what does each number of rings mean?

Tags: iphone

Let's say someone blocked your number one week ago. When you tried calling them you'd get one ring and it goes straight to voicemail... or no rings and it goes straight to voicemail.

A week later you call and you get two long rings before it goes to voicemail. Does that mean they unblocked your number?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on *how* they blocked your number. However, generally the number of rings is not a good indicator of whether you've been blocked.

I would suggest solving by talking to or contacting the organisation or person that has blocked your number.